# Bluetooth headphones and speakers stop after some minutes

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones, bluetooth-speaker

I have an XPS 13 from 2019 with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have this persistent problem with any audio devices where they will connect and work perfectly, and after 10 minutes the sound will stop. The bluetooth manager will still show everything working normally and applications like Spotify will continue playing. Usually when bluetooth stops working, Spotify and Youtube will stop playing until audio can be played.

I have looked through other questions but can't find a solution, because in my case everything works perfectly for a while, and devices connect automatically without any problem. When I find this problem, restarting Bluetooth in the settings fixes the issue. Any tips that might solve my problem are greatly appreciated.

This is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:1653]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
03:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3] (rev 02)
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:8152 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0c45:6723 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

One of the times the sound stopped playing, I tried pressing the "Play" button on the headphones. This caused the headphones to realize the connection was broken and warn me the connection with the laptop had ended.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have added the output of that.

Comment: Same issue on my MSI Prestige 15 (A10SC) running Linux Mint 19.3 (kernel 5.3.0-28-generic) with my Bose 700. Everything works as expected until the sound stops.

Answer (score 0):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

and reboot.

That should fix the issue when Wi-Fi and BT are used simultaneously on 2.4GHz.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering what this answer means https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132509/difference-between-bt-coex-active-n-and-bt-coex-active-1